# Calculating area on N points

Tags: matlab, polygon, area

Im trying to calculate numerically an area of different shapes where the only thing I know about them is the (x,y) of each corner.

For example the shapes are:

[image]
[image]

P.s. The points inside the shape are for other calculation, I only need the area of the most outer shape.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create polygon, and use `polyarea` function.

Given x,y location of corners than:

```
Area=polyarea(x,y)
```